# Is there a more efficient way to create nlog database targets?

Tags: c#, sql-server, nlog

I often create logs that have a lot of custom columns like:

```xml
<target xsi:type="Database" name="Log" dbProvider="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="...">
      <commandText>
        INSERT
        INTO [dbo].[Log]([Foo], [Bar], ...)
        VALUES(@FOO, @BAR, ...)
      </commandText>
      <parameter name="@FOO" layout="..." />
      <parameter name="@BAR" layout="..." />
      ...   
</target>
```

but I don't really like how I have to repeat the names of the columns three times for each of them. It's difficult to maintain and easy to make a mistake.

Is there an easier and more efficient way to create NLog database targets?

Can NLog infer the insert from the parameters alone? It would be great if I just could write the schema and table name, the parameters and the `INSERT` is pretty *obvious* so it actually could be build automatically. Is there such a mechanism yet?

I've added the `c#` tag because if there is a programmatic solution I prefer `c#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to t3chb0t answer.

You could loop over all the database targets after the configuration changes:

```
private void Main() //or application_start
{
    //init
    GenerateDatabaseTargetQueries();

    //update when config changes
    LogManager.ConfigurationReloaded += (sender, args) => GenerateDatabaseTargetQueries();
}

public void GenerateDatabaseTargetQueries()
{
    var databaseTargets = LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets.OfType<DatabaseTarget>();
    foreach (var databaseTarget in databaseTargets)
    {
        //todo good init capacity for StringBuilder
        var queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        queryBuilder.Append("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Log]");
        foreach (var dbParameter in databaseTarget.Parameters)
        {
            //append all the parameters to the query
        }
        databaseTarget.CommandText = queryBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea. I didn't even expect there is such an event.

Comment: Update, it should be ConfigurationReloaded instead of ConfigurationChanged  to be sure. I have updated the example

Answer (score 1):

I found a way. You need to update the `CommandText` of the `DatabaseTarget`.

```
var config = NLog.LogManager.Configuration;
var dbTarget = config.AllTargets[0] as DatabaseTarget;
dbTarget.CommandText = "INSERT...";
```

*see also  [Auto-INSERT query for NLog](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140751/auto-insert-query-for-nlog) on CodeReview*